Excel custom filter hierarchy
Is there any way in excel to have a custom filter on a column that works like when the filter is on the date column when you get a hierarchy of year>month>day>time
If it could work where a delimiter was specified like |
The filter would then create the hierarchy based on delimited cell value
eg top level | second level | third level etc

From your question it is not clear what you tried and how your data looks like. Potentially this could be useful as a dependent dropdown list. But you would need to provide more clarity on what exactly you are looking for.

Without sample data, where to start?

You could make use of =FILTER(Range, MONTH(DateRange)=MonthNumber) or instead of MONTH, Year, day..
